# Create new DB with SQLite4Java

Tags: java, sqlite

How can I create a new DB with SQLite4Java? 
For example after trying to open connection to a DB that does not exist yet.

```
SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(new File("DB.db"));
try {
    db.open(true);
} catch (SQLiteException e) {
    <<CREATE DB>>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass true to the open() method, the database will be created if it doesn't exist.